# im getting " no such table: main.auth_user__old" when i tried to save something in admin/message/post/add/ in my local server

Tags: django, sqlite

I have logged in as a superuser and i have tried to save some text but im getting an error here's my whole code.  https://bitbucket.org/bhaskarpraveen/message/src/master/first_project/message/models.py

this is my code in models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
         """A string representation of the model."""
         return self.text[:50]
```

> OperationalError at /admin/message/post/add/
>   no such table: main.auth_user__old
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/message/post/add/
>   Django Version: 2.1.4
>   Exception Type: OperationalError
>   Exception Value:
>   no such table: main.auth_user__old
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\conda\cond\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 296
>   Python Executable:  C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.7.2
>   Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\Praveen\Desktop\messaging\first_project',
>    'C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\python37.zip',
>    'C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\DLLs',
>    'C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib',
>    'C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv',
>    'C:\Users\Praveen\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages']
>   Server time:    Wed, 30 Jan 2019 13:49:21 +000

Comment: I think you forgot to migrate your database!

Answer (score 0):

That error doesn't relate to the model in question so you likely forgot to migrate the database, or were modifying something else not shown, such as the user model or Django admin internals. You are probably only noticing the error now because you don't have a test to catch it. If neither of these are correct go back to the last time you were 100% sure it worked and retrace your steps. The goal is to isolate the problem since I a pretty sure that model is totally fine so it must be something else that changed.